# I have three values and budget and i need to buy a product at the best price in python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, tuples

The condition is as follows:
I have a budget of 500 EUR.
There are three bikes at different prices.
I need to buy a bike at the best price

If I set the budget to 0 then I get an else print, but if I change the budget to 1 then I get a successful if print even though my budget is less than the price of the bike.

Maybe you can help and explain what I'm doing wrong?

CODE:

```
budget = 500
bikeUnivega = 375
bikeKalkhoff = 449
bikeFocus = 462

bikeCatalogList = (bikeUnivega, bikeKalkhoff, bikeFocus)
lowestBikePrice = bikeCatalogList.index(min(bikeCatalogList))

if budget > lowestBikePrice:
    print(f'I Will buy the bike for the lowest price of {bikeCatalogList[lowestBikePrice]} EUR.')
else:
    print('I dont have enough money for the bike. I will save money until next year.')
```

I tried to find the information on google, but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things I've noticed in your code:

For starters, your list is using () like a tuple, instead of [].

Next is that lowestBikePrice is not returning the value stored in the variable, but its index.

So, if you were to get the min, it returns a 0 bc the lowest value variable is in position 0.
If you were to use a max instead, it would return a 2.

lastly your f string is hashing your list for an item lowestBikePrice which doesn't exist in the list.

Comment: The culprit of the issue is, as you mention, the index being stored instead of the price. Simply removing the bikeCatalogList.index() and instead storing the min should fix the issue